# How do I adjust my cursor to normal size in Medal?

Tags: digital-recording

Why is my cursor non existent? I'm trying to get it to the right size. The cursor should align exactly with the circle (inside the circle with no overlap, but the exact same size). That's how it looks for me, but it looks different once Medal clips it. How do I change this?

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about https://medal.tv/ ? What platform are you using? What version, etc.

Comment: Yes, windows Medal.tv. Didn't say anything else about the version